# Sql Server get current date time in Europe

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

The above query in SQL Server will return current date and time in USA because server is located in USA. How can I modify it to retrieve current date and time in Europe?

Comment: Which timezone in Europe? Please define Europe for your purposes, as the definition of the continent isn't constant, and it spans *n* timezones.

Comment: "current date and time in USA" - no, unfortunately. USA also has 4 timezones. `GETDATE()` returns the server's local time, no matter which timezone and country it's in, not the USA's time.

Comment: .. and because most servers are used by clients in multiple time zones, more asnd more DBAs are setting system clocks on servers to GMT... so GetDate() returns UTC or GGMT time, not local

Comment: Also: which **version** of SQL Server? SQL Server **2008** introduced great new features to deal with this (like `SWITCHOFFSET`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:  Set @Offset =

- 0 for Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) - Great Britain,
- 1 for Central European Time (CET)    -Netherlands, Germnany, France
  etc,
- 2 for Eastern European Time (EET)  Czechoslovakia, Hungary, etc.

  `Set @Offset = 0, 1, 2 ...`
  `Declare @offset tinyInt = 0`
  `Select GetUtcDate() + @offset/24.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use SwitchDateTimeOffset function with the datetimeoffset data type (requires SQL Server 2008 or higher).

Demo query:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeZone (ID int identity,
                    LocalTime datetimeoffset);
INSERT INTO TimeZone values ('2008-05-21 17:50:01.1234567 -08:00'),
                           ('2008-05-21 18:50:01.1234567 -08:00');  
SELECT * FROM TimeZone;
SELECT ID, SWITCHOFFSET(LocalTime,'+01:00') [time for new time zone]
   FROM TimeZone;
DROP TABLE TimeZone;
```

In your scenario this becomes:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'+01:00')
```

As pointed out by p.campbell, you still have to decide which timezone represents 'Europe' for your purposes.